# Map each element of array with its own method using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing

I have an array of class objects called "rules".

self.rules looks like this

```
[<creative_task.rules.rules.Rule object at 0x7fde7a33f518>, <creative_task.rules.rules.Rule object at 0x7fde7a33f830>, <creative_task.rules.rules.Rule object at 0x7fde7a33f888>, <creative_task.rules.rules.Rule object at 0x7fde7a33f8e0>]
```

This Rule class has method self.check that validates data that stored in it.

There are a lot of rules to be validated: requested value is MORE, LESS, EQUALS, BETWEEN, POSITIVE, NEGATIVE respecting to the value from database.
Each such rule on self.check function call makes a call to Clickhouse database to validate itself.

Basically, when I need to validate array of rules I call check_all function that validates all the Rules like this 
**rules=[r.check(asset, context) for r in self.rules]**
:

```
    def check_all(self, asset: dict, context: dict = None) -> RuleGroupResult:
        context = {} if context is None else context
        return RuleGroupResult(
            identifier=self.identifier,
            rules=[r.check(asset, context) for r in self.rules],
            groups=[g.check(asset, context) for g in self.groups],
            logical_operator=self.logical_operator,
        )
```

These rules are not depending on each other.

Now I want to make this kind of validation to be a parallel process. So I need to call Rule.check method for each Rule in array, but this calls should occur simultaneously

Comment: You could make several other processes to run your check, passing the arguments in a queue? How are you doing your multiprocessing?

Comment: you need to provide more details. Note on terminology: you have a *list* of *objects*. Unless you are actually working with an array? Are you? "Class object" refers to the classes themselves, i.e. `class Foo: pass` then `Foo` is a class object (classes are first-class objects in Python), and `foo_instance = Foo()` is an instance of the class Foo. In any case, you need to provide more details about what you are actually doing with multiprocessing, ideally by showing us a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga tried to make my question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with `Pool.map`, along with `operator.methodcaller`, since your arguments are all the same, and the method has the same name on each object:

```
import multiprocessing as mp  # Top of file
from operator import methodcaller

def check_all(self, asset: dict, context: dict = None) -> RuleGroupResult:
    context = {} if context is None else context
    with mp.Pool() as pool:  # Create pool
        return RuleGroupResult(
            identifier=self.identifier,
            rules=pool.map(methodcaller('check', asset, context), self.rules),  # Map in parallel
            groups=pool.map(methodcaller('check', asset, context), self.groups),
            logical_operator=self.logical_operator,
        )
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thx a lot